# Remember what was the last remote branch pushed to from current branch

Tags: git, android-studio

I often have multiple branches and I do PRs. Currently whenever I want to push a branch I have to **manually** search and select the remote corresponding branch I want to push to.

Therefore I don't want it to select this random branch by default.

[image]

But I want it to select by default the last target branch used from last time I pushed the current branch.

[image]

Is there anyway or trick that allows me to do this?

I have a guess. It might be selecting `tachi:master` because the branch was setup to track upstream which is `tachi:master`. I prefer to keep it this way so I can still pull normally but make the push be tracked to a different `origin:branch` if that makes sense?

I have tried to do this by using

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

It seems this actually works for the terminal. Currently when I do a `git push` through the terminal, it would correctly push to correct remote branches `origin:branch_name`.  However there is no difference in the android studio push interface, it would still select the same as pull upstream branch. And what confirms this even more is the little arrow indicators that show there are outgoing commits although the default push remotes are actually up-to-date.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Easy: Don't run `git push`. Run your own command that runs `git push` with the parameters you prefer. (Now, convincing some GUI to do that...well, this is why I don't like GUIs.)

Comment: @torek I have managed to correctly setup git push defaults, the issue is that android studio doesn't respect these options.

Comment: Same issue then. It's not a *Git* problem, it's a GUI problem.